# What does "low-growing" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What does **low-growing** mean in the following sentence?

> *She planted some "low-growing" stuff.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means plants that don't grow very tall. There are plants that will keep growing upwards indefinitely, but there are also plants that reach a certain height and stay there, and/or that grow sideways instead of upwards. The latter kinds can be described as "low-growing".

Answer (score 1):

Plants that do not grow very high.  See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/low-growing).